# How to use Linux aliases in Python3 script

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, alias, csh

I'm trying to use linux alias in python script to get required information
For that I need to run linux alias in my python3 script.

For example:
I have alias ll 'ls -rtl' and I'm running "ll" alias as shown below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4zm7.png)

```
import subprocess

print('{:/^100}'.format(f' pd_env detect '))
get_pd_env_cmd = subprocess.run('ll', shell=True,
                                    capture_output=True, text=True,
                                    executable='/bin/csh'
                                    )
print(get_pd_env_cmd.stdout)
print('-'*100)
print(get_pd_env_cmd.stderr)
```

But as result I'm getting only error as shown in second screenshot.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IqibV.png)

> ////////////////////////////////////////// pd_env detect ///////////////////////////////////////////
>
> ---
>
> ll: Command not found.

My linux shell is csh.
I tried to run it with interactive shell this  " csh -ic command ".
As I'm understanding the issue is that python script does not recognize linux aliases.
Case is that I always use same alias which references to different versions of tool depended from setups. So the interface of usage alias is same and I cannot know which version is used in alias. Thats cause why I cannot just replace it by direct command.
Then from outputs I'll parse needed data and save.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code - they are impossible to run and not searchable. Please show actual command you ran instead of just alluding to it with `csh ....`

Comment: Not sure why you would want to use an alias in a non-interactive command, or why you would want to use `csh`. How about `subprocess.run(['ls', '-l'], capture_output=True, text=True)`. And what are you going to do with the output anyway - you shouldn't parse it as that is error-prone. So, please say what you plan to do with the output.

Comment: Case is that I always use same alias which references to different versions of tool depended from setups. So the interface of usage alias is same and I cannot know which version is used in alias. Thats cause why I cannot just replace it by direct command.
Then from outputs I'll parse needed data and save.

Comment: Ok, what is *"needed data"* please? I am trying to help you get a solid solution and parsing the output from `ls` is never recommended.

Answer (score 0):

testing your code I found that in my environment, shell aliases are not available in python and I get `/usr/bin/alias: line 2: alias: ll: not found`.

My idea was to run `alias ll` in python subprocess which returns

```
alias ll='ls -l --color=auto'
```

easy to filter with string operations like

```
alias_response.split('=')[1].split("'")[0]
```

and use that string as command in a following subprocess call

just out of my head ... hope it helps

Comment: I also face to same issue. Case is that I always use same alias which references to different versions of tool depended from setups. So the interface of usage alias is same and I cannot know which version is used in alias. Thats cause why I cannot just replace it by direct command.